# Is there a javascript library can help me to operate textarea?

Tags: javascript, textarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i get cursor position in a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891444/how-can-i-get-cursor-position-in-a-textarea)

I want some basic but common operations on textarea with javascript, such as

- get the cursor position
- set the cursor position
- insert some text to the cursor position
- select all text in textarea
- select a range of text
- insert some text to the cursor position, and select it immediately.

I hope it working cross-browers.

Is there such javascript library?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891444/how-can-i-get-cursor-position-in-a-textarea/1909997#1909997

Comment: Or: http://code.google.com/p/rangy/.

Comment: @pimvdb, `rangy` is powerful, but it's too big(39K after compressed).

Comment: I think this is not exactly the same as that one. I don't only want to get the cursor, but also replace, reselect some text. That question doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [jQuery plug-in I've written](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/) that does all of this. There's a standalone version too but it needs a little bit of tidying. If you'd prefer no jQuery then it would give me a reason to sort it out and release it.

Comment: thank you, it's small and clear, I like it. I' prefer jQuery-version :)