# Get keyup position using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get caret position in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea)

If i type * in anywhere in the html textarea control i need to get the current position on keyup event like `"Welcome* to jQuery"`. So i have * after Welcome means at 8th position. Let me know if anybody can help me on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work. (note: with quotes it's at 8 else at 7)

```
$("#tf").on('keyup', function(){
    console.log($(this).val().indexOf('*'));
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/hc6ZH/

**UPDATE:** solution with multiple *

```
$("#tf").on('keyup', function(){
    var pos = [],
        lastOc = 0,
        p = $(this).val().indexOf('*',lastOc);

    while( p !== -1){
        pos.push(p);
        lastOc = p +1;
        p = $(this).val().indexOf('*',lastOc);
    }
    console.log(pos);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/hc6ZH/1/

***UPDATE:*** giving only the position of the * char you just typed

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    $.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
        var el = $(this).get(0);
        var pos = 0;
        if('selectionStart' in el) {
            pos = el.selectionStart;
        } else if('selection' in document) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        return pos;
    }
})(jQuery);

$("#tf").on('keypress', function(e){
    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if(key === '*') {
        var position = $(this).getCursorPosition();
        console.log(position);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/esDTj/1/

Comment: What if you press * twice? Then you will only get the index of the first one.

Comment: @MiniGod is right. I need the position of * that fires the keyup event not the others.

Comment: Didn't knew that was required I'll update ;)

Comment: @Pradeep http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea

Comment: Your answer only lists all occurrences of `*`? How about this http://jsfiddle.net/esDTj/

Comment: @MiniGod your fiddle isn't working at all. keyup seems to return bad keycodes, so I switched to keypress. Nevertheless, I must agree I misinterpreted. I updated my answer and applied one of the solutions in the post Pradeep found. (just to set it straight)

Comment: You consolidated very well. Appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Below link helped me to resolve this using jQuery itself.

[Cursor position in a textarea (character index, not x/y coordinates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891444/how-can-i-get-cursor-position-in-a-textarea)

Thanks for your efforts guys.

Comment: Oeps, misinterpreted the question. Now that I see what you needed ;) good 4 you! Cheers!