# detect character before the cursor after keyup in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement tagging just like what facebook does with @friendname. I have a textarea and I wanted to detect when a user typed in @. How do I do so using a keyup listener? Is it possible to get the entered text using keyup? Here's what I have now

```
$("#recommendTextArea").keyup(function () {
        var content = $(this).val(); //content Box Data
        var go = content.match(start); //content Matching @
        var name = content.match(word); //content Matching @friendname

        console.log(content[content.length-1]);
        //If @ available
        if(go.length > 0)
        {
            //if @abc avalable
            if(name.length > 0)
            {
               //do something here
            }
        }
    });
```

Most importantly what I need is the index of the'@' that the user just entered.

Comment: Why do you need the '@' index? Can you provide a little jsfiddle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i get cursor position in a textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891444/how-can-i-get-cursor-position-in-a-textarea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/esDTj/10/)

```
      (function ($, undefined) {
    $.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
        var el = $(this).get(0);
        var pos = 0;
        if('selectionStart' in el) {
            pos = el.selectionStart;
        } else if('selection' in document) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        return pos;
    }
})(jQuery);

$("#recommendTextArea").on('keypress', function(e){
    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if(key === '*') {
        var position = $(this).getCursorPosition();
        alert(position); // It is the position
        alert($(this).val()); // This is the value 
    } 
});​
```

I made some changes [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795089/get-keyup-position-using-jquery).

Comment: this doesn't solve it.. what if you have two @. How do you know which one is the one that you just typed.

Comment: using lastIndexOf() also doesn't solve it. What if I move the cursor to the middle of the string and typed in @, but I also have another @ in the end?

Comment: You did not specified that in the question

Comment: Which @ index you want to take.Just typed one ?

Comment: Yes I wanted the index of the @ that the user just inputted.. that's all

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29996/discussion-between-adit-and-psr)

Answer (score 1):

To detect a `@`, you'd do something like :

```
$("#recommendTextArea").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which===50) {
        alert('you typed @');
    }
});
```

and `this.value` get's you whatever is typed into the textarea, and you'll need a regex to get what's between `@` and the first following space, or something similar depending on how you intend to do this ?

To get a name, you can do something like this :

```
var _name = false;

$("#recommendTextArea").keyup(function (e) {
    if (_name) {
        $('#name').text('name : ' + this.value.substring( this.value.lastIndexOf('@') ) )
    }
    if (e.which === 50) {
        _name = true;
    }
    if (e.which === 32) {
        _name = false;
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/F5Hmj/3/)

This is just a quick demo, building something that always works and accounts for every possible outcome will be a lot more work than this.

**EDIT:**

> Most importantly what I need is the index of the'@' that the user just
>   entered.

that would be `this.value.lastIndexOf('@')`

**EDIT AGAIN:**

To get the names typed in the textarea regardless of cursor position, number of names etc. you'll have to use a regex, here's a quick example that gets all and any names typed in, as long as they start with a @, and ends with a blank space :

```
$("#recommendTextArea").keyup(function (e) {
    var names = this.value.match(/@(.*?)\s/g);
    $('#name').html('names typed : <br/><br/>' + names.join('<br/>'));
});
```

**FIDDLE**

Comment: is there a way to get the index of this?

Comment: `this.value.lastIndexOf('@')`

Comment: that wouldn't work.. If I had an @ at the end and I moved the cursor to the middle of the string.. then this would failed the case

Comment: @adit - yes it would, the only way to get proper results would be to use a regular expression and parse the string to get any potential usenames, but you did ask for the index of the last @, and that's what you got ?

Comment: @adit - edited the answer again, and added a regex method that should get you any and all names typed in.

Comment: You are awesome! Working perfect.