# get cursor position on key up

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection-api

I'm not very experienced at javascript or jquery. I need to figure out whether the user's cursor is in the last position of a text input field with a maxlength of 3 on key up. If so, switch focus to the next field. I've seen this done a lot on forms so I think everyone can understand the semi common functionality I'm looking for. The input fields in question are not of type text, but of type tel

I tried to find an answer to this question here, but I couldn't understand any of the answers to what might be a similar question that I'm asking, but not exactly the same. For example, it mentions selectionStart and selectionEnd but I can't find where these are really explained. It seems to me like they involve selected text, but that's not what I want.

I want this to be checked while the user is typing. Here's what I have tried just to see if I can get a correct value back, but it returns undefined.

```
$("#phone1").keyup(function(){
    var phone = $("#phone1");
    alert(phone.selectionEnd);
});
```

Sorry if I don't understand some of this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for?

```
(function ($, undefined) {
        $.phone1.getCursorPosition = function() {
            var el = $(this).get(0);
            var pos = 0;
            if('selectionStart' in el) {
                pos = el.selectionStart;
            } else if('selection' in document) {
                el.focus();
                var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
                var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
                Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
                pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
            }
            return pos;
        }
    })(jQuery);

    $("#phone1").on('keypress', function(e){
        var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        if(key === '*') {
            var position = $(this).getCursorPosition();
            console.log(position);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });​
```

font: [Get keyup position using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795089/get-keyup-position-using-jquery) is pretty similar I think..

Comment: Just look at the link if you have problems.. It's pretty similar to your.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the jquery event that you should bind is 'change' event, this will fire on every change that will occur like new input, or delete input etc.

e.g.

```
(function(){

    $('#telNo').on('input' , function(){
            if($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength'))
            $(this).next('input').focus();
  });

})();
```

in above code, this code will shift the focus onto the next input, regardless of type

```
$(this).next('input').focus();
```

and the HTML markup should be like this:

```
<input type="tel" maxlength="4" id="telNo">
<input type="text" maxlength="4" id="text">
```

Here is a working fiddle

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytayvn2p/)