# CKEditor 4: Keep cursor position after manually creating inline instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, ckeditor

When CKEditor 4 is in AutoInline mode, it creates its instances on page load. The user can then click any editable field and get going. Since I may have many instances on one page, I want to create them on demand (on focus) to speed up loading time using:

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

$(".editable").focus(function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass("cke_editable_inline")) CKEDITOR.inline(this);
});
```

It works, but the cursor jumps to the beginning of the textarea once the instance is created. Is there a way of avoiding this?

I have read the threads referenced in this topic:
[Keep cursor position in CKEditor when focus changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016205/keep-cursor-position-in-ckeditor-when-focus-changes)
and others regarding selections and ranges, but none seems to be working. 
I have tried solutions involving editor.getSelection(), but it was always null.

I would appreciate any hint, thank you!

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm looking at the same thing at the moment without finding a working solution.