# Angular 2 - Get removed character from input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there anyway to detect removed character from a text using `ngModel` in Angular 2 ?

I want something like:

**Original text**: `@Hello World !`

**Modified text** : `Hello World !`

***Console.log***

```
Removed character: '@'
```

I've found a cool example on Javascript with Jquery by **Arie Xiao** below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17005983/5668956

But I wonder if I can use another thing beside Jquery, as I find that Jquery is pretty hard to implement in Angular 2

Comment: Create 2 variables, 1 for ngModel and another to handle the difference.. In your `input` you use `(change)` to execute a method in your `component` and manipulate the *difference*.

Comment: can you not just hold on to a previous value and compare what's changed when change happens?

Comment: you can listen onChanges event

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a Forms controller for acting on changes on the input field. The snippet displays the character add or deleted from the input field.
Check out my  [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gZCnvrcocNKXkIw8w88M?p=preview) to see the code running.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <input type="text" [formControl]="form"  class="form-control" >
    <h3 *ngIf="initial">
      Text <span [style.color]="textadd ? 'green' : 'red'" > {{textadd ? "add" : "removed" }} </span>: {{change}}
    </h3>
  `,
})
export class App {
  form;
  textadd;
  text = "@Hello World!";
  initial = false;
  change;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormControl({ value: this.text, disabled: false });

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      let change;
      if (val.length > this.text.length) {
        change = val;
        for (let variable of this.text) {
          change = change.replace(variable, '');
          this.textadd = true;
        }
      } else {
        change = this.text;
        for (let variable of val) {
          change = change.replace(variable, '');
          this.textadd = false;
        }
      }
      this.change = change;
      this.text = val;
      this.initial = true;
    });
  }
}
```