# Prevent removing special character in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent the user from deleting any "/" character in a textbox when pressing `backspace` or `canc`.

For example:

If the textbox value is `2014/09/`, and the user presses backspace, the "/" character will not be removed.

How can I do it in the `keyup` or `keydown` evenets?

```
$("#textboxId").keyup(function(){

   // any idea

});
```

Comment: you dont want to delete `/` ?

Comment: I would suggest you to use [MASKED INPUT PLUGIN](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) I think thats what you require

Comment: @Khaleel yes i dont want remove /

Comment: @Satpal i dont want use mask plugin

Comment: Can you get the textbox value as a string, get the substring before the last /, and set the substring as the textbox's new value?

Comment: @cameron yes , i can get it as string, can you show me sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three situations:

1. The user presses `backspace` and deletes the char before the cursor
2. The user presses `canc` and deletes the char after the cursor
3. The user selects the text and presses `backspace` or `canc` and deletes the selected text

So you have to work around all these different situations.

**This code will work:**

```
$('#textareaId')[0].addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var start = this.selectionStart,
        end = this.selectionEnd,
        value = this.value,
        key = e.keyCode;

    if (key == 8 && value[start-1] == '/') e.preventDefault();
    if (key == 46 && value[start] == '/') e.preventDefault();
    if ((key == 8 || key == 46) && value.substring(start, end).indexOf('/') != -1) e.preventDefault();

}, false);
```

**WORKING EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/MeBeiM/7hdb3472/1**

Comment: @AminJafari I didn't select the jQuery library, sorry. It works fine now.

Comment: It works almost fine. The problem is when I completely select the textbox and type something will remove / also, but it works fine on select+delete.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using the string operations

Check my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/7ek11cfs/21/

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(e) {
   textValue = $(this).val();
});

$('textarea').keyup(function(e) {
 if(textValue.charAt(textValue.length-1)=='/')
 {
   $('textarea').val(textValue);
 }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @MarcoBonelli which is expected as solution is works in this. how you claim it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

here you go => **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1zqjzbg3/)**

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    $.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
        var el = $(this).get(0);
        var pos = 0;
        if('selectionStart' in el) {
            pos = el.selectionStart;
        } else if('selection' in document) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        return pos;
    }
})(jQuery);

$("#textboxId").keydown(function(e){
    var currentPos=$(this).getCursorPosition();
    var lastChar=$(this).val().substr((currentPos- $(this).val().length)- 1);
    if(e.which==8 && lastChar.match(/^\//g) ){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

I took a bit help from [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891444/cursor-position-in-a-textarea-character-index-not-x-y-coordinates/1909997#1909997) for the function to identify the current position of cursor.

NOTE that in oppose to all the other answers and ideas found, this will ACTUALLY work like a mask and will not be removed even if the cursor is in the middle of the text!

Comment: You are making it a really mooooore complicated than it really is.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli yes, because I want it to work in  all the situations with no exception

Comment: If you put the caret at the beginning and use the CANC key it will delete all the text...