# difference between jQuery keypress and javascript onkeypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's difference between jQuery keypress and JavaScript onkeypress?

When I'm trying to get cursor's start/end position in textbox/textarea in jquery I must use this one (using caret plugin)

```
$("#sometextbox").keypress(function(e){
   var stratposition = this.caret().start;
   var endposition= this.caret().end;
});
```

but when onkeypress

```
<textarea onkeypress="return makeGeo(this,event);"></textarea>

function makeGeo(ob,e) {
    var startPos = ob.selectionStart;
    var endPos = ob.selectionEnd;

}
```

Is there any way to get cursor's positions in jquery without caret plugin?

Comment: This post has several new ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891444/cursor-position-in-a-textarea-character-index-not-x-y-coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the jQuery event handler, simply use `this.selectionStart` and `this.selectionEnd`:

```js
$("#sometextbox").keypress(function(e) {
  var startPos = this.selectionStart;
  var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
  console.log(startPos, endPos);
}).focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="sometextbox"></textarea>
```

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.10.2 version and I've allready try this one and get undefined :( and btw in chrome this method works fine but no tin IE (doc mode 7)

Comment: jQuery version shouldn't matter.  I've changed to 1.10.2 in my answer.  What browser are you using?

Comment: In Chrome this method works fine but not in IE (doc mode 7)

Comment: Ouch, sorry you have to support that.  @abraararique posted a good link in his comment.